# ssl on a local dev server

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2

I am running ubuntu as a testing server on my laptop.  I am attempting to set up some of the test sites with self signed ssl certificates.  I think I have everything correct except perhaps the apache 2 conf files.

When creating the cerificates I gave the common name as *.hr4.mdev. "mdev" is what I have arbitrarily called my local dev environment.

So I modified my existing conf file to listen on 443 instead on 80 (line 1) and I added lines 6, 7 and 8.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin  myemail@mydomain.com
  ServerName   marino.hr4.mdev
  ServerAlias  *.marino.hr4.mdev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/marino.hr4/htdocs
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
  <Directory /var/www/marino.hr4/htdocs>
    php_value include_path /var/www/marino.hr4/htdocs
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/www/marino.hr4/logs/error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
  LogLevel debug

  CustomLog /var/www/marino.hr4/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I go to the site (https://marino.hr4.mdev) I am advised that "It works!" Which is reassuring on a certain level, but it is not the content that I expected to see.

---

Having referenced tremor's link, my conf file now looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.73.128:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

  ServerAdmin  bernard@theminery.com
  ServerName   marino.hr4.mdev
  ServerAlias  *.marino.hr4.mdev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/marino.hr4/htdocs

  <Directory /var/www/marino.hr4/htdocs>
    php_value include_path /var/www/marino.hr4/htdocs
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/www/marino.hr4/logs/error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
  LogLevel debug

  CustomLog /var/www/marino.hr4/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

after restarting Apache I am asked to add a security exception, which is fine, but I am then kicked to another site I have set up on my machine.

Comment: Simply make your virtual host your default host, the "It works" is the default apache directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I modified the ports.conf file and added 443 to the Listen directive, so now it reads:

```
Listen 80 443
<IfModule ssl_module>
  Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
  listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I also changed the first line of my conf file from

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.73.128:443>
```

back to

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

Special thanks to tremor for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Add NameVirtualHost directive, something like this perhaps?

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 443
```

Your apache server is obviously serving up it's default server "It works" instead of your website.

Here is some supporting information from apache: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

Edit:

Potentially move your virtual host to the first referenced vhost in the conf file, default is selected based on order.

Comment: When I add those lines to my conf file and restart apache2 I receive a notification "The apache2 configtest failed."  it also tells me that "NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release"

Comment: Thanks tremor, it looks like I'm a little further ahead than before.  Please see my edits above.

Comment: oh you must be using apache 2.4? I didnt think that was packaged with Centos. NameVirtualHost may be deprecated after 2.2.  Also, the order in which the virtualhosts are listed is the order of which one become default.. so, which ever you want to be default should be the first on in the order in the .conf file.